# Divide rectangle to equal square pieces each containing only one specific element

Tags: algorithm

**Problem description**

On one of the sites you periodically meets captcha, the solution of which takes a long time. You want to write a robot to automate the task.
Captcha is a photo that should be divided into rectangular fragments. All fragments should have the same area, but there may be different sizes of sides. Each fragment must contain exactly one road sign.

Your colleagues have already preprocessed the photo. They divided it into small square parts and defined the main object for each of them.

The photo gets to you in the form of a line:

```
"TRABWARH  
 THSCAHAW  
 WWBSCWAA  
 CACACHCR"
```

*Object designation*:
S-road sign (sign), 
T-tree (tree), 
R-road (road), 
B-building (building),
C-car (car), 
A - pet (animal),
W-pond (water),
H-man (human)

**Notes**

- The number of road signs in the photo is always more than 1 and less than 10.
- Each fragment must be a rectangle.
- The area of each of the resulting fragments should be the same, but the size may vary.
- In the output array, the fragments should go from top to bottom and from left to right (relative to the upper left corner).
- If there are multiple solutions, comparing the methods gives priority to the one with the largest width of the first different fragment.
- If there is no solution, return an empty array.

**Simple test cases**:

```
"TRABWARH\nTHSCAHAW\nWWBSCWAA\nCACACHCR"
["TRABWARH\nTHSCAHAW","WWBSCWAA\nCACACHCR"]

"CSRARHAR\nCWAHCBSW\nABWBSWBA\nRBSBTABH"
["CSRARHAR","CWAHCBSW","ABWBSWBA","RBSBTABH"]

"HSRSTBHC\nCAWTRTBT\nWBATSTRA\nTWRBRTRR\nRWTABSHB\nTWCBWBCA"
["HS\nCA\nWB\nTW\nRW\nTW","RSTBHC\nWTRTBT","ATSTRA\nRBRTRR","TABSHB\nCBWBCA"]

"TSRSBWAC\nASCSWBTC\nTTAHTABC\nAHWTRWWA"
[]
```

My solution is just to compare all valid rectangles, but its time consuming. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "all valid rectangles"? You have the number of road signs, so you know the total number of rectangles and hence their area. Factor the area to find valid edge length. This should reduce the number of valid rectangles greatly. With this, you can start in the top-left corner and backtrack if the rectangles do not fit anymore. But maybe you already tried this?

Comment: @tobias_k Yes, it's what my solution do, I think: https://pastebin.com/9TBmt1Yr Sorry for messy javascript.